# Permanent URL masking for mirroring website using php and htaccess

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, dns, mirroring

First
Let say that i have **www.domain.com** that are client site and user login and do all the thing that he want (site is main and he use POST method for login adn other things and HEADER redirect if login are success)
But i not want user to see original  **www.domain.com** i want when they enter  **www.name.com/dashboard.php** to see content from **www.domain.com/dashboard.php** but him URL bar to show **www.name.com/dashboard.php** ..and like this all other page that can have original **www.domain.com** 
I found this site:
 http://www.htmlremix.com/css/permanent-url-masking-for-mirroring-website-using-php-and-htaccess
Adn use script but when are entered user login detail noting happen!! Just home page reload.
I try everything that i think may be cause problem and not found how to solv it .. So please help me!!
Thanks Allot
P.S. If have some more good way that can i use also will help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that cant be achieve with a htaccess file.
You need different things.
possible solution could be:
apache mod proxy so you could proxy everything through that url.
the other way could be a php written some kind of proxy. Working with curl or and remote configured fopen.

But be careful to also send the post data and the cookies, otherwise the user session could not be handled if its cookie based.

If both domains are on the same server you could easily set this up with a vhost configuration in apache/nginx what ever you are using.

Comment: No they are not on same domain(also i will use this for some sort of reseller panel) and site work with SESSION. I read something about proxy_mod and if i right this feature is not sported from normal hosting plans(only from big dedicated or VPS )

Comment: then im afraid to say you have to write that on your own. With curl, cookie handling, response handling etc.